# django, alterar o valor de um campo do form quando eu seleciono itens em outro campo

Tags: django

Tenho um form que cadastra uma venda, seleciono o cliente, o funcionario(vendedor), e os itens(produtos) vendidos e estou colocando o valor total da venda manualmente. O que eu gostaria era que ao selecionar os itens, de alguma forma, o preço de cada item fosse somado e o valor total jogado automaticamente no campo valor da venda... como posso fazer isso?

```
# form: 

class VendaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Venda
        fields = ('cliente', 'func', 'valor', 'itens')

# view:

def efetuar_venda(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VendaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            venda = form.save()
            venda.save()
            return redirect('/calcados/', {})
    else:
        form = VendaForm()
        return render(request, 'calcados/cadastrar.html', {'form': form})

# the template cadastrar.html only shows the form given
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro como você quer fazer isso, se é no `template` ou na `view`. Se for no template seria dúvida de JavaScript.

Comment: Sem dúvida. Javascript/ Jquery seria a solução indicada..

Comment: obg, com jQuery deve ficar bom, mas acabei fazendo uma gambiarra, na view de adicionar um item na venda eu chamo a função declarada no modelo venda que atualiza o total somando o preço de todos os itens atrelados a venda usando item_set.all() para pegar todos itens.

Comment: você pode usar javascript/jquery, assim pegarias os valores no template, trabalhando mais o lado cliente var valor = $(id ou class.....).val( ); ou $(id ou class.....).data( nome );